# I keep getting this error in my code. Why does this keep happening? type object 'RefreshToken' has no attribute 'for_user'

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, attributes, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

i am trying to create a login view using django rest framework simplejwt and i am using this function to create tokens

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken

def get_tokens_for_user(user):
    refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)

    return {
        'refresh': str(refresh),
        'access': str(refresh.access_token),
    }
```

however /i keep getting this error

```
     type object 'RefreshToken' has no attribute 'for_user'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for generating a token for user you have to use `Token` not `RefreshToken`.

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import Token

def get_tokens_for_user(user):
    refresh = Token.for_user(user)

    return {
        'access': str(refresh)
    }
```

Comment: sorry i didn't mention this but i need both the access and the refresh token doing that returns only the access token